# long ans = ((long) INT_MIN) * 2 - 1; causing a warning because of integer overflow

Tags: c, integer-overflow

I have this in my code and it is causing the warning that follows:

```
long ans = ((long) INT_MIN) * 2 - 1;
```

The warning that I get is:

```
warning: integer overflow detected: op "*"
```

I have included limits.h so that I could use INT_MIN

```
#include <limits.h>
```

Comment: aside from the reason: why do you need to do that?

Comment: If `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long)`, what else do you expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that the calculation will overflow the range of `long`.  Signed overflow yields undefined behavior.

The only correlation between the range of values representable by `long` and the value `INT_MIN` is that `INT_MIN` is representable as a `long`.  There is no guarantee that one less than twice `INT_MIN` is representable as a `long`.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows x86, using the Visual C++ compiler, [`long` is 4-bytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), same as `int`.  Try `long long`